# Clear multiple ranges across multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to run a script that will go through all my sheets (except the last couple of sheets) and clear the contents of a number of ranges within.

The code below works, but is incredibly slow, which leads to a timeout error.

I've looked around as best I can to find out how to shorten or speed it up. To my limited knowledge, it's already pretty short and concise.

Am I missing a trick here?

```js
  function clearranges() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

for(var i = 0; i < 46; i++){
var sheet=allsheets[i]

 sheet.getRange('D5:AH12').clearContent();
 sheet.getRange('A14:A33').clearContent();
 sheet.getRange('D14:AH33').clearContent();
 sheet.getRange('A9').clearContent();
 sheet.getRange('B5:B12').clearContent();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows:

```js
function clearrangeX() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
    var sheet = allsheets[i]

    sheet.getRange(9, 1, 1, 1).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(14, 1, 20, 1).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(5, 2, 8, 1).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(5, 4, 8, 31).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(14, 4, 20, 31).clearContent();


  }
}
```

Instead of using the A1 notation, replace the code with index, row notation where the first value is the row to begin on, second value is the column to begin on, third value is number of rows to process, fourth is number of columns to process.

This took the runtime from >360 seconds to 0.981 seconds!